# AWS ELB Redirect to another Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a site set up like https://example.co and want requests from https://example.com redirected to the .co version. I'm using AWS EC2 for hosting. What is the most cost efficient way to do this?  Initial thought was to set up an additional ELB for the example.com and have it forward to our backend instances, which would take care of the redirect (in nginx).

Comment: So to be clear you want to redirect https://example.com to https://example.co right? You don't need to set up a additional ELB.

Comment: From what I understand, you can only have 1 SSL per ELB. I want `https://example.com` to redirect to `https://example.co`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most cost effective way would be to only use one ELB and once SSL certificate, and point both domains to that ELB.
Your understanding that an ELB can only host one SSL certificate is correct (once certificate per listener/port).

However, multi-domain SSL certificates do exist: you can get one SSL certificate that has can be used both for example.com and example.co.
This way, you can have one ELB that accepts https traffic for both domains.

The second setup is to get the redirects to work. You can set that up at the web server on the instance(s) behind the ELB. Configure virtual hosts for example.com and example.co, and make the virtual host for example.com serve redirects to example.co.

So actually that's pretty close to your initial plan, with the exception that you only need to have one ELB when you use a multi-domain SSL certificate.

A multi-domain certificate is usually a bit more expensive than a regular certificate, but well below the costs of an additional ELB (which starts at something like $35 per month, if i recall correctly).

Comment: This sounds really promising. I think the multi-domain certificate is the easiest solution; we already have the redirect set up. From what I understand, you can use multi-domain certificates in AWS Certificate Manager, which are free. Are there are any browser issues with multi-domain certs?

Comment: No, not as far as I know. They're just regular SSL certificates.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a DNS `CNAME` record to point `example.com` to `example.co`. This will then use the SSL certificate for `example.co` regardless of which domain users use:

- Configure an **Elastic Load Balancer** with an SSL certificate for `example.co`
- Configure both `example.co` and `example.com` as Hosted Zones in **Amazon Route 53**:

  - For `example.co`, use an `A` record with `Alias=YES` to point to the Elastic Load Balancer
  - For `example.com`, use a `CNAME` record to redirect to `example.co`

This way, HTTPS requests to both domains should point to the same ELB be sent to the same servers.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. There's some online discussions about Server Alternate Names that can make it work, so it might not work "out of the box" as described above.

Comment: Is what you are suggesting a redirect? Won't `example.com` still be the address appearing in the users' browser? (despite the fact that they will be served content from the load balancer)...I was looking for a 301 redirect...